# getopts does not find missing arguments on multiple options

Tags: bash

Bash 5.1.16

The following code doesn't work for me:

```
optstring=":l:s:vh"
while getopts ${optstring} flag; do
  case ${flag} in
    (l) listsfile=${OPTARG};;
    (s) sourcedir=/${OPTARG};;
    (v) verbose=true;;
    (h) help=true;;
    (:)
      echo "Option -${OPTARG} requires an argument!"
      showhelpscreen
      exit 1
      ;;
    (?)
      echo "Invalid options"
      showhelpscreen
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "went through"
```

- If I provide '-l' without a value, showhelpscreen (:) is called (OK)
- If I provide '-l' with a value, all is going well and "went through" is printed (OK)
- If I provide '-l -s', "went through" is printed. Either of the options need a value but none is given. In my opinion (:) should be triggered, but it isn't.

Comment: If `-l` requires a value (which it does) and you type `-l -s`, then `-s` is the argument to `-l` (and you have not actually passed the `-s` option).

Answer (score 0):

As larsks said, getopts interpretes a second 'option' (in this case -s) as a value of the preceding option. You'll need to care on error handling on your own if values are missing.